# Given a method name as string, how to get the method instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, wrapper

I've a class `Client` which has many methods:

```
class Client:
    def compute(self, arg):
          #code
    #more methods
```

All the methods of this class runs *synchronously*. I want to run them *asynchronously*. There are too many ways to accomplish this. But I'm thinking along these lines:

```
AsyncClient = make_async(Client) #make all methods of Client async, etc!

client = AsyncClient()           #create an instance of AsyncClient

client.async_compute(arg)        #compute asynchronously
client.compute(arg)              #synchronous method should still exist!
```

Alright, that looks too ambitious, and I feel it can be done.

So far I've written this:

```
def make_async(cls):

     class async_cls(cls):  #derive from the given class

         def __getattr__(self, attr):
               for i in dir(cls):
                   if ("async_" + i) == attr:
                         #THE PROBLEM IS HERE
                         #how to get the method with name <i>?
                         return cls.__getattr__(i) # DOES NOT WORK

     return async_cls
```

As you see the comment in the code above, the problem is to get the method given its name as string. How to do that? Once I get the method, I would wrap it in `async_caller` method, etc  — the rest of the work I hope I can do myself.

Comment: I think __getattr__ just works with class instance, not class. Use getattr(cls, method_name) instead will resolve the problem.

Comment: Also, in your __getattr__, you should split the method name and check if it exists in base class by getattr, loop and compare is bad performance.

Comment: @Tarzan: Ohh.. yes, that works. Can you please post an answer so I can upvote and accept (if it is the best among all)?

Comment: It's okay. I've just post the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `__getattr__` just works with class instance, not class. Use `getattr(cls, method_name)` instead, it will solve the problem.

```
getattr(cls, method_name)
```